# Haskell Function which combines Lists

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I want to write a recursive function that gets two lists + a conditional as input, and outputs all possible tuples with one element each from the 1st and 2nd lists that satisfy the condition.

It should look something like this:

```
Combine [1,2,3] [5,6,7] (\a b -> a+b > 7) -> [(1,7),(2,6),(2,7),(3,5),(3,6),(3,7)]
```

I got this atm:

```
Combine:: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)] 
Combine [] ys = []
Combine xs [] = []
Combine (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : Combine xs ys
```

However, it does not yet create all possible combinations and does not filter by condition. I really don't know how to figure this out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: first, function names _must_ start with lower-case letter. Second, your problem can be solved in one line with list comprehension. If it helps,  It would be a very similar solution as if you write it in `python` with list comprehension

Comment: Should be done without a  list comprehension

Comment: Then you have to write an auxiliar function (named it `aux` for example). The auxliar function `aux` takes one element `x` and a list `ys`, and produces the the list of tuples `(x,y)` such that the condition `x + y > 7` holds. Then you have the resursive step using the fact that `tuples [1,2,3] [4,5,6] = [(1,4), (1,5), (1,5)] ++ tuples [2,3] [4,5,6]` . I think this is enough information to solve your assignment

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a recursive function, but you need a higher order function.

```
combinationsFilter :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
combinationsFilter f as bs = filter (uncurry f) [(a, b) | a <- as, b <- bs]
```

[(a, b) | a <- as, b <- bs] generates all combinations of a and b.

filter... just filters the list by condition.

uncurry needed if you want pass a function with type (a -> b -> c), but not ((a, b) -> c). It converts one to the other.